# Java: Trigger after x number of exceptions in y time

Tags: java, api

I have an API that connects to two backends, one is the standard backend(fast response time, but may sometimes be down) and the other is the high availability backend(slower response time but always up). I would like to switch over to the HA backend after x number of exceptions in y number of seconds. So for example if in the last 60 seconds I get 10 exceptions from the standard backend, I would like to switch over.

What would be the best way to keep track of exceptions in a rolling time period in Java?

Comment: Sounds like you want NewRelic or Splunk, both of which can monitor application logs for errors and page engineers when things are going south.

Comment: I want this to be in the code. This is an automatic switch from regular mode, to HA mode. I am already using splunk for monitoring

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to adapt Guava's [RateLimiter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) to accomplish your goals. You could acquire synchronously whenever an exception is thrown, and if the acquisition fails (returns false), you'll know that you've hit your failure rate, and you can switch over to your HA endpoint.